# iPhone 4s and 5s

Tags: icloud

I use two I phone. I changed SIM card of my iPhone 4s and replaced it with a new one. But I don't see the contacts that are in my iphone5s on my 4s. I also have same Apple id

Comment: are both phones using the same appleid?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your Contacts set to be backed up to iCloud on both devices. Settings > iCloud > Contacts. (The switch next to Contacts need to be pushed to the right and displaying green.)

[image]